# How to uninstall generator-jhipster

Tags: jhipster, yarnpkg

I've installed `jhipster-generator` version 5.1.0 using `yarn`.

Today, I need to uninstall this version, in order to downgrade from version 5.1.0 to version 5.0.1.

When trying:

```
yarn global remove jhispter
```

I receive an error message:

```
yarn global v1.7.0
[1/2]   Removing module jhispter@5.1.0...
error This module isn't specified in a manifest.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

What is the correct way to uninstall generator-jhipster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used wrong name, it's generator-jhipster not jhipster

```
yarn global remove generator-jhipster
```

Answer (score 8):

```
npm remove -g generator-jhipster
```

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall jhipster use as below. It worked for me.

```
npm remove generator-jhipster
```